# Is it possible to Disable Firebase for a particular Flavor?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a flutter project that is collegated at Firebase. But, I created a flavor and I don't want that flavor is attached with the Firebase. How I can do that? This is the Build.grandle part

```
flavorDimensions "version"
  productFlavors {
      wifi{
          dimension "version"
          applicationId "uk.co.everythingeverywhere.myee-wifi-controls"
      }
  }

  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
  apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
  apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
```

UPDATE:
I tried to define a variable that, when I launch the flavor config, change the value of the flavor. So I do a control (with if-statement) and if it is true, apply the plugin. Else no. But It didn't work